# Use Regex to find pattern that includes special characters and reject if they follow other patterns

Tags: regex

I want to find one of this patterns within a text:

```
space or line start + 4 digits + space or line end

space or line start + 4 digits + "-" (optional) + 1 character (digit or letter "x") + space or line end
```

It would look like any of this:

```
8638-x
86381
8638-1
8638
```

I tried to use the below but, according to regex101.com, the "-x" is not being selected

```
(\d{4})|((\d{4}\-\d{1})|(\d{4}\-(?i)[x]))
```

It is important that the below pattern is rejected if found (in case my OCR fails to structure properly):

```
"\d{3}\.?\d{3}?\d{3}\-?\d{2}"
```

Comment: Do you mean like `\b\d{4}(?:-?[\dx])?\b` https://regex101.com/r/RMXGWL/1 or if lookarounds are supported `(?<!\S)\d{4}(?:-?[\dx])?(?!\S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match 4 digits followed by an optional group that would match an optional hyphen and either a digits or a `x`

```
\b\d{4}(?:-?[\dx])?\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\d{4}` Match 4 digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-?[\dx]` Match optional `-` and either a digit or `x`
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RMXGWL/1/)

If lookarounds are supported, you might use:

```
(?<!\S)\d{4}(?:-?[\dx])?(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/daFl7p/1)

Comment: Seems to work fine. Did you consider that it should be placed between spaces or in the end of a line?

Comment: @abutremutante The pattern with the lookarounds `(?<!\S)\d{4}(?:-?[\dx])?(?!\S)` will match when there is a space or the start / end of the string. If lookarounds are not supported, you could use a capturing group `(?: |^)(\d{4}(?:-?[\dx])?)(?: |$)`  https://regex101.com/r/PlNBKs/1